# Convert ISO-8601 varchar (0000-00-00T00:00:00+00:00) to datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, iso8601

How can I convert 2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30 to DateTime in SQL?

2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30 is a varchar field. I need to convert this into DateTime to compare this to a date field.
suggest me a query to Convert (2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30) into DateTime

Comment: Are you starting off with a text date, or something else?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: 2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30 is  varchar .. I need to convert this into date

Comment: What's wrong with `CONVERT`? What value are you expecting for `2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30`?

Comment: What is the expected result? `2019-07-01 00:00:00` or `2019-06-30 18:30:00`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert To date :

```
select cast('2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30' as Date)
```

Convert To time:

```
select cast('2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30' as Time)
```

Convert To datetime :

```
select convert(datetime2, '2019-07-01T10:00:30+05:30',0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these..

```
 select cast(convert(datetime2, '2019-07-01T10:00:30+05:30',0) as datetime)

 select convert(datetime2, '2019-07-01T10:00:30+05:30',0)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a combination of `CONVERT` on the timestamp without the timezone component, then use `TODATETIMEOFFSET` with the timezone portion to get the final result:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30' AS dt
)

SELECT
    TODATETIMEOFFSET(CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(dt, 19), 126), RIGHT(dt, 6)) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

This outputs:

```
01/07/2019 00:00:00 +05:30
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SQL Server truncates the time zone information when converting from `datetimeoffset` to date`or`datetime`.  But, you can calculate the offset and add it back in:

```
select dateadd(minute,
               datediff(minute, convert(datetimeoffset, dt), convert(datetime, convert(datetimeoffset, dt))),
               convert(datetime, convert(datetimeoffset, dt))
              )
from (values ('2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30')) v(dt);
```

For your particular timezone, the date at midnight matches the UTC date, so you are safe.  I'm on the other side of the world, so this would be a more important consideration in the "western" world ("west" being west of UTC).

Answer (score 0):

The following query will convert the given VARCHAR to DATETIME value:

```
DECLARE @DateVal AS VARCHAR (30) = '2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:30';
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@DateVal, 0, CHARINDEX('+', @DateVal)), 'T', ' ') AS DATETIME);
```